# How can I alphabetize a multi line record from a text file?

Tags: bash, scripts

Hi I'm working with bash script and I have example.txt below. How can I alphabetize the following 4 information about restaurants by the restaurant name and print it out? Note that the format when printed alphabetically that it should remain the same as below including city, state, address, phone.

```
Restaurant: McDonalds 
City: Miami
State: Florida
Address: 123 Biscayne Blvd
Phone: 91341

Restaurant: Five guys
City: Atlanta
State: Georgia
Address: 123 Peachtree Rd
Phone: 9234211

Restaurant: KFC
City: NYC
State: NY
Address: 123 Madison Square
Phone: 95311

Restaurant: Taco Bell
City: LA
State: CA
Address: 123 Rodeo Drive
Phone: 911
```

Answer (score 5):

Here is a solution using `awk`:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS="\n";RS=""} {r[$1]=$0} END{n = asort(r); for (i=1;i<=n;i++){print r[i] "\n"}}' restaurants 
Restaurant: Five guys
City: Atlanta
State: Georgia
Address: 123 Peachtree Rd
Phone: 9234211

Restaurant: KFC
City: NYC
State: NY
Address: 123 Madison Square
Phone: 95311

Restaurant: McDonalds 
City: Miami
State: Florida
Address: 123 Biscayne Blvd
Phone: 91341

Restaurant: Taco Bell
City: LA
State: CA
Address: 123 Rodeo Drive
Phone: 911
```

`awk` reads in the file one record at a time.  We define the record separator, `RS`, to be `""` so that records are separated by a blank line.  All the records are read into an array `r`.  At the end, the array `r` is sorted and printed.

As @Sadi points out in the comments, the `awk` command is adaptable to use in a pipeline:

```
cat restaurants | awk 'BEGIN{FS="\n";RS=""} {r[$1]=$0} END{n = asort(r); for (i=1;i<=n;i++){print r[i] "\n"}}' >sorted_list_of_restaurants
```

Comment: +1 for quick and much better answer while I was writing one with **sed**. Just a minor note: beginning this with `cat "YourFile" |` and ending with `> "YourFile-Sorted"` might sometimes be preferrable.

Comment: @Sadi Thank you.  I have added your bash pipeline form to the answer.